# W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to load a String url into mediaPlayer but getting following error

```
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open https://somewebsite.com/video.mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:
```

When I access the link via browser the video plays fine.

Following is my code.

In Swipe Adapter (It loads from a list, and when you swipe  it loads more)

```
void setVideoData(VideosListModel videosListModel) {

    vvVideo.setVideoPath(videosListModel.getVideo_url());
    vvVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pbProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mp.start();

            float videoRatio = mp.getVideoWidth() / (float) mp.getVideoHeight();
            float screenRatio = vvVideo.getWidth() / (float) vvVideo.getHeight();
            float scale = videoRatio / screenRatio;
            if (scale >= 1f) {
                vvVideo.setScaleX(scale);
            } else {
                vvVideo.setScaleY(1f / scale);
            }
        }
    });
    vvVideo.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Interestingly when I upload using API27 from a Real Phone it works, but when using API31 Redmi Note 10 Pro Max it does not work for the same video.  Even though there is error on API27 but it still plays.

Comment: prolly because url is not a path ... see documentation for better method

Comment: it is a path https://somewebsite.com/video.mp4

Comment: Not a path to the file on file system

Comment: so how should i solve  it

Comment: Hehe I was wrong ... `public void setVideoPath(String path) {
        setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    }` so using  `setVideoURI` would not  help ... anyway ... do you have internet permissions?

Comment: Yes <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: i suggest you to use exoplayer [link](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro#4)

Answer (score -4):

If you not add this in Manifest.xml

and error may be in onPrepared

Comment: What did you mean with "this"?